# How to programmatically assign the textbox size to auto?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I am newbie to windows phone development. I need to assign the textblock size to auto pro grammatically. How to do this ?

Comment: <TextBlock Width="*"/> or <TextBlock Width="Auto"/>

Comment: Just a small add on to @FaisalHafeez 's answer. * means take up all remaining space where as Auto means Take up what you need.

Comment: Flexible layouts generally use containers for layout and allow element widths to be calculated.  You can place the textblock in a grid and set the textblock's HorizontalAlignment property to "Stretch" (which is the default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation on MSDN for [FrameworkElement.Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx)

> In addition to acceptable Double values, this property can also be Double.NaN. This is how you specify auto sizing behavior. In XAML you set the value to the string "Auto" (case insensitive) to enable the auto sizing behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Any numerical double or single value to be not setted in. NET can be passed as "type". NaN, or "not a number".

Double.NaN
Single.NaN

In the case of control properties, such as height or width, this indicates the uninitialized or auto.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers do not respond to the actual question, which related to setting the width/height PROGRAMMATICALLY, not in XAML. To do so, simply create the control and add it to its container without setting the height property - if it is a text control (textbox, textblock), make sure the .TextWrapping property is set to TextWrapping.Wrap (also suggested: set the VerticalAlignment property to System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top).